# Private class name abbreviation techniques?

Tags: c++, class, typedef, private, c-preprocessor

My class uses the PImpl idiom and looks something like this:

```
// In LongDescriptiveClassName.hpp

class LongDescriptiveClassName
{
public:
    // Stuff...

private:
    struct LongDescriptiveClassNameData;

    LongDescriptiveClassNameData &Data;
};
```

In the .cpp file, I declare/define the private struct:

```
// In LongDescriptiveClassName.cpp

struct LongDescriptiveClassName::LongDescriptiveClassNameData
{
    void PrivateMethod1();
    void PrivateMethod2();
    // and so on...
};

void LongDescriptiveClassName::LongDescriptiveClassNameData::PrivateMethod1()
{
    // Stuff...
}

void LongDescriptiveClassName::LongDescriptiveClassNameData::PrivateMethod2()
{
    // Stuff...
}
```

This is painful for me to read.  **Is there a way that I can abbreviate the names leading up to the private methods?**

My understanding is that I can't `typedef` it in the .cpp file because the PImpl struct is private.  Would it be an evil to use `#define`?

```
#define ShortName LongDescriptiveClassName::LongDescriptiveClassNameData

struct ShortName
{
    // ...
};

void ShortName::PrivateMethod1()
// ...
```

This .cpp file is the only source file that would need to abbreviate it, and then only for method definitions.  What do you recommend?

Comment: Instead of using `LongDescriptiveClassNameData` use `ShortNameData`. Much shorter. If you're worried about conflicts why not use namespaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class name is already a namespace, so there's no reason to give the impl such a long name:

```
class LongDescriptiveClassName
{
public:
    // Stuff...

private:
    struct Impl;

    // shared_ptr is also an option if that's
    // the semantics you want.    
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> Data;
};

// and off in the implementation, we have...
struct LongDescriptiveClassName::Impl
{
    void PrivateMethod1();
    void PrivateMethod2();
    // and so on...
};

void LongDescriptiveClassName::Impl::PrivateMethod1()
{
    // Stuff...
}
```

It works just fine.

Incidentally, your code is not an example of the pimpl idiom. The "p" in "pimpl" means "pointer", and this is important. A reference means that the object does not own its implementation.

It's not necessarily wrong; there are sometimes good reasons to wrap a reference in a class, but it's not the pimpl idiom.

Comment: That's a good point, I suppose the implementation doesn't need such a long name.  However, if I did want to shorten the name further for use only in this one .cpp file, what is the harm of using the `#define` directive?

Oh, I thought the "p" stood for "private".  Thanks for the info.

Comment: The only reason not to use `#define` in that case is that C-style macros are always to be avoided if it's possible and reasonable to do so. Macros subvert the C++ type system, and the C++ type system is usually your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure to understand your problem but it seems that a proper use of the `using` keyword should help a lot. Isn't

```
using ShortName = LongDescriptiveClassName::LongDescriptiveClassNameData
```

what you are looking for ?

Note this only work is `LongDescriptiveClassNameData` is a type not a data.

Comment: He said why you can't do this: `LongDescriptiveClassNameData` is private.

Answer (score 0):

While @Pseudonym's solution is absolutely fine, I prefer to use names with initial upper case only for types, so I think I'd just do:

```
class LongDescriptiveClassName {
private:
    struct Data;

    Data &data;
};
```

Comment: I usually don't call my impls "data" because I often put member functions in there too. It's often not just private data that you want to hide, but private behaviour too. Your mileage may, of course, vary.

Comment: I was just reusing the original names. I would only consider Data suitable for a bunch of attributes representing, say, persistent state or something similar

Answer (score 0):

I like to call it `Impl`, or `Detail` (though the latter is common as a `namespace detail`, also).